# How to display ü created in python and displayed in html?

Tags: python, django, symbols

I've created a django app in German.

I have the following in python:

```
error = 'Füllen Sie alle Pflichtfelder aus'
return HttpResponse(render_to_string(page.html, {'error':error}))
```

My page.html would be simple:

```
<p> {{error}} </p>
```

What should I do so that the letter ü can be displayed in the html? I tried writting `&uuml;` in the python code, but I did not work.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the original code? What do you actually get?

Comment: Using umlauts should work without problems. At least it does for me.

Answer (score 1):

With questions like these, it helps if you describe exactly what the error is that you're seeing.

There are a couple issues with what you're doing, the biggest being that you're using strings, not unicode objects.

[Here's the documentation on how to properly create a unicode object in Python](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)

In Python, you can have two different types of strings. One uses only ASCII characters, the other uses any unicode character. You specify a unicode string by surrounding it with a u'' instead of ''. Also, by default, Python doesn't load in your source code as unicode, so you want to encode any strings you have in it (or change the encoding of the file, as shown in the link above) So your line should become:

```
error = u'F\u00FCllen Sie alle Pflichtfelder aus'
```

Then everything should work out fine!

After that, as a purely style thing, you probably want to change the last line in your view to just be:

```
return render_to_response(page.html, {'error':error})
```

which is effectively the same but a nice shortcut.

Comment: I changed `erro`r as you mentioned here before and it worked. There was no need to change the line `return HttpResponse(render_to_string(page.html, {'error':error }))` . Thanks!

Comment: yeah, the second line change was more of a shortcut thing, figured you'd want to know about the shortcut. i'll edit the answer to make that more clear. if the change worked, please accept the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `{{ error|safe }}` with ü as `&uuml`. Alternatively save the corresponding .py file as UTF-8 encoded. Hope this leads into the right direction.